# Question about the definitons of convergent in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While learning measure theory I have stumbled upon 3 different definitions of "convergence in measure".

Convergent in measure:
$f_n$ converges in measure to $f$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ $\mu(${$x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|> \epsilon$}$) \rightarrow 0$.

Cauchy in measure:
Let $\delta, \epsilon >0$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n,m \geq N$
$\mu(${$x:|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|>\delta$}$)\leq \epsilon$.

Now it is somewhat confusing to get a defintion where we only use $\epsilon$ and one where we use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

In "Cauchy in measure", we could have obviously also written: Let $\delta >0$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n,m \geq N$
$\mu(${$x:|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|>\delta$}$) \rightarrow 0$.

But while searching for more information I have also found the following definition:

Convergence in measure:
Let $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$
$\mu(${$x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon$}$)\leq \epsilon$.

This definition now is very confusing. Why is there one definition that uses $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ and one that only uses $\epsilon$? Is there some relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: They are all equivalent. (Cauchy in measure, maybe not, but the two definitions you wrote for convergence in measure are the same)

Comment: @Andrew I don't really see why. Is there a way to show that those are equivalent.

Comment: That the first implies the second is tautological. Now suppose $f_n \to f$ in the sense of the second definition. Let $\delta,\epsilon>0$ be given. Set $\tau = (\delta \wedge \epsilon)/2$.  Choose $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\mu\{|f_n-f|>\tau\}<\tau$. Namely, $\mu\{|f_n-f|>\delta\}\leq \mu\{|f_n-f|>\tau\}<\tau \leq \epsilon$

Comment: @Andrew Thank you